# First element of JSON Object as a Key

Tags: reactjs, json, react-admin

I'm trying to get an object named as the ID of a user.

Here's my JSON :

```
"createdAt": 1631189580468,
        "custom": {},
        "id": "IDOFCONVO",
        "lastMessage": {
            "attachment": null,
            "createdAt": 1631189829568,
            "custom": {},
            "id": "msg_0OY4vwTcyMh2dkW2SNFPTlhE2E61p",
        },
        "participants": {
            "XXXXX123": {
                "access": "ReadWrite",
                "notify": true
            }
        },
        "photoUrl": null,
        "topicId": null,
        "welcomeMessages": null
    },
```

participants contains id's of users, with it's attribute. I first tried with `<ReferenceManyField>` like so :

```
<ReferenceManyField label="User" target="participants" reference="users">
   <SingleFieldList>
      <ChipField source="name" />
   </SingleFieldList>
</ReferenceManyField>
```

But it just returns every user's name from my user endpoint.

How could i specify that the first element of the Object `"participants"` that it is the id of the User ?

Comment: There's no array at all in the json you posted, `participants` is an object.

Comment: Are you able to change your data structure at all?
ReferenceFields usually like to operate off a flat list of id's.

Comment: @DoctorAgon sadly not, i'm guessing i will need to make some kind of function to store the element as ID's and then inject it somehow ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a [<FunctionField />](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Fields.html#functionfield) where you can reshape the data in the render function.

```
<FunctionField
  label='User'
  render={record => {
    if (record === undefined || record === null) return null;
    // Transform the data however you need here
    const newData = Object.keys(record.participants);
    return (
      <ReferenceManyField
        label='User' target='participants' reference='users'
        record={{...record, participants: newData}}
      >
        <SingleFieldList>
          <ChipField source='name' />
        </SingleFieldList>
      </ReferenceManyField>
    )
  }}
/>
```